# hiveql conditional sum across rows in hiveql

Tags: hiveql

I am not able to figure out the hive query for following scenario:

Data has columns for `customer_id` and `transaction purchase timestamp`. Other two columns are `transaction_item_return` (possible values: `yes`/`no`) and `return timestamp` for each transaction.

Now, the requirement is: For each `customer_id`, get counts of all returns (where value=yes) that have `return timestamp` before a given transaction's `purchase timestamp`. I have spent a lot of time writing the query and searching across various forums. Any help/guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: `select customer_id, count(case when transaction_item_return = 'yes' and return_timestamp < transaction_purchase_timestamp then 1 end) as returns_before_purchase from my_table group by customer_id`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, we don't want to compare return_timestamp and transaction_purchase_timestamp for a given row. We want to compare the transaction_purchase_timestamp of a given transaction with all other transactions rows where return_timestamp is less than given transaction's purchase_timestamp (by customer_id)